# Installation of texlive fails while downloading luatex (checksums differ)

Tags: luatex, texlive, installing

I installed texlive 2020 some time ago without any problems. While updating it some issue with luatex occured and luatex stopper working. So I uninstalled texlive and decided to reinstall it.
However, the installation fails when trying to download luatex:

```
Installing [34/64, time/total: 00:26/00:58]: luahbtex.win32 [1515k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ\ihYA0IWEp_/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=5e395b24bd9e710be88f1f2e2a3bd18022daf3cf1e2be18d27192eccea50f5ddaa122c6ae8cd4cce6b54d3a8608ae9e119d0dbf25d1e37aa2da8a986aa0a0c70, arg=04f90e04de858fb120852cebd84671f026b355fd1ac1acb5fee48f559f06709f8c25fa4f2ccf84a602de92ff728de5bfdc97610325c803540b349c2c3f1faf18
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2330: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1976: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1811: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1727: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1552: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:2160: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:980: main::do_install_packages
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:732: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ\ihYA0IWEp_/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\Ku6tO0tyna
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install luahbtex.win32
Will be retried later.
```

I switched to minimal installation to save time, tried different mirrors, but still get the same error.

I am running Windows 10 as administrator with Avast turned off. The same problem occurs on the other machine as well.

Full log:

```
TeX Live installer invocation: C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl -from_ext_gui -repository http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet -lang en_us 
Loading http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
Installing TeX Live 2020 from: http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified)
Platform: win32 => 'Windows'
Distribution: net  (downloading)
Using URL: http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
Directory for temporary files: C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ
Installer revision: 54993
Database revision: 55117
Settings:
  TEXDIR: "C:/texlive/2020"
  TEXMFCONFIG: "~/.texlive2020/texmf-config"
  TEXMFHOME: "~/texmf"
  TEXMFLOCAL: "C:/texlive/texmf-local"
  TEXMFSYSCONFIG: "C:/texlive/2020/texmf-config"
  TEXMFSYSVAR: "C:/texlive/2020/texmf-var"
  TEXMFVAR: "~/.texlive2020/texmf-var"
  binary_aarch64-linux: ""
  binary_amd64-freebsd: ""
  binary_amd64-netbsd: ""
  binary_armhf-linux: ""
  binary_i386-cygwin: ""
  binary_i386-freebsd: ""
  binary_i386-linux: ""
  binary_i386-netbsd: ""
  binary_i386-solaris: ""
  binary_win32: "1"
  binary_x86_64-cygwin: ""
  binary_x86_64-darwin: ""
  binary_x86_64-darwinlegacy: ""
  binary_x86_64-linux: ""
  binary_x86_64-linuxmusl: ""
  binary_x86_64-solaris: ""
  collection-basic: "1"
  collection-bibtexextra: ""
  collection-binextra: ""
  collection-context: ""
  collection-fontsextra: ""
  collection-fontsrecommended: ""
  collection-fontutils: ""
  collection-formatsextra: ""
  collection-games: ""
  collection-humanities: ""
  collection-langarabic: ""
  collection-langchinese: ""
  collection-langcjk: ""
  collection-langcyrillic: ""
  collection-langczechslovak: ""
  collection-langenglish: ""
  collection-langeuropean: ""
  collection-langfrench: ""
  collection-langgerman: ""
  collection-langgreek: ""
  collection-langitalian: ""
  collection-langjapanese: ""
  collection-langkorean: ""
  collection-langother: ""
  collection-langpolish: ""
  collection-langportuguese: ""
  collection-langspanish: ""
  collection-latex: ""
  collection-latexextra: ""
  collection-latexrecommended: ""
  collection-luatex: ""
  collection-mathscience: ""
  collection-metapost: ""
  collection-music: ""
  collection-pictures: ""
  collection-plaingeneric: ""
  collection-pstricks: ""
  collection-publishers: ""
  collection-texworks: ""
  collection-wintools: "1"
  collection-xetex: ""
  doc_splitting_supported: "1"
  inst_platform: "win32"
  instopt_adjustpath: "1"
  instopt_adjustrepo: "1"
  instopt_desktop_integration: "1"
  instopt_file_assocs: "1"
  instopt_letter: ""
  instopt_portable: ""
  instopt_write18_restricted: "1"
  n_collections_available: "41"
  n_collections_selected: "2"
  n_systems_available: "16"
  n_systems_selected: "1"
  scheme-basic: ""
  scheme-context: ""
  scheme-custom: ""
  scheme-full: ""
  scheme-gust: ""
  scheme-infraonly: ""
  scheme-medium: ""
  scheme-minimal: "1"
  scheme-small: ""
  scheme-tetex: ""
  selected_scheme: "scheme-minimal"
  src_splitting_supported: "1"
  this_platform: "win32"
  tlpdbopt_autobackup: "1"
  tlpdbopt_backupdir: "tlpkg/backups"
  tlpdbopt_create_formats: "1"
  tlpdbopt_desktop_integration: "1"
  tlpdbopt_file_assocs: "1"
  tlpdbopt_generate_updmap: ""
  tlpdbopt_install_docfiles: "1"
  tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles: "1"
  tlpdbopt_location: "http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet"
  tlpdbopt_post_code: "1"
  tlpdbopt_sys_bin: "/usr/local/bin"
  tlpdbopt_sys_info: "/usr/local/share/info"
  tlpdbopt_sys_man: "/usr/local/share/man"
  tlpdbopt_w32_multi_user: ""
  total_size: "226"
Installing to: C:/texlive/2020
Not an admin install; not making read-only
Not an admin install; not making read-only
Not an admin install; not making read-only
Not an admin install; not making read-only
Installing [01/64, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: texlive.infra [420k]
Installing [02/64, time/total: 00:01/02:06]: texlive.infra.win32 [1397k]
Installing [03/64, time/total: 00:02/00:58]: tlperl.win32 [6816k]
Installing [04/64, time/total: 00:07/00:43]: amsfonts [4725k]
Installing [05/64, time/total: 00:10/00:39]: bibtex [404k]
Installing [06/64, time/total: 00:11/00:42]: bibtex.win32 [41k]
Installing [07/64, time/total: 00:11/00:42]: cm [235k]
Installing [08/64, time/total: 00:12/00:45]: collection-basic [1k]
Installing [09/64, time/total: 00:12/00:45]: collection-wintools [1k]
Installing [10/64, time/total: 00:12/00:45]: colorprofiles [113k]
Installing [11/64, time/total: 00:13/00:48]: dehyph [46k]
Installing [12/64, time/total: 00:13/00:48]: dviout.win32 [2183k]
postaction install fileassoc for dviout.win32: .dvi, TL.DVIOUT.view.2020
Installing [13/64, time/total: 00:14/00:45]: dvipdfmx [3077k]
Installing [14/64, time/total: 00:16/00:43]: dvipdfmx.win32 [315k]
Installing [15/64, time/total: 00:17/00:45]: dvips [566k]
Installing [16/64, time/total: 00:17/00:44]: dvips.win32 [92k]
Installing [17/64, time/total: 00:18/00:46]: ec [280k]
Installing [18/64, time/total: 00:19/00:48]: enctex [272k]
Installing [19/64, time/total: 00:19/00:48]: etex [197k]
Installing [20/64, time/total: 00:20/00:50]: etex-pkg [7k]
Installing [21/64, time/total: 00:20/00:50]: glyphlist [25k]
Installing [22/64, time/total: 00:20/00:50]: graphics-def [13k]
Installing [23/64, time/total: 00:21/00:52]: hyph-utf8 [312k]
Installing [24/64, time/total: 00:21/00:51]: hyphen-base [22k]
Installing [25/64, time/total: 00:22/00:54]: hyphenex [187k]
Installing [26/64, time/total: 00:22/00:53]: ifplatform [156k]
Installing [27/64, time/total: 00:23/00:55]: iftex [217k]
Installing [28/64, time/total: 00:23/00:55]: knuth-lib [30k]
Installing [29/64, time/total: 00:23/00:55]: knuth-local [23k]
Installing [30/64, time/total: 00:24/00:57]: kpathsea [1074k]
Installing [31/64, time/total: 00:25/00:57]: kpathsea.win32 [476k]
Installing [32/64, time/total: 00:25/00:56]: lua-alt-getopt [6k]
Installing [33/64, time/total: 00:26/00:58]: luahbtex [30k]
Installing [34/64, time/total: 00:26/00:58]: luahbtex.win32 [1515k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ\ihYA0IWEp_/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=5e395b24bd9e710be88f1f2e2a3bd18022daf3cf1e2be18d27192eccea50f5ddaa122c6ae8cd4cce6b54d3a8608ae9e119d0dbf25d1e37aa2da8a986aa0a0c70, arg=04f90e04de858fb120852cebd84671f026b355fd1ac1acb5fee48f559f06709f8c25fa4f2ccf84a602de92ff728de5bfdc97610325c803540b349c2c3f1faf18
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2330: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1976: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1811: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1727: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1552: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:2160: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:980: main::do_install_packages
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:732: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ\ihYA0IWEp_/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\Ku6tO0tyna
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install luahbtex.win32
Will be retried later.
Installing [35/64, time/total: 00:27/01:00]: luatex [1867k]
Installing [36/64, time/total: 00:28/00:58]: luatex.win32 [1780k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ\yKP08lsWBY/luatex.win32.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=2e22def143606949b8eab4ce7a0850768e1d78ed9bccdfc35db54f6caabb22788f324c323c4b9f51827463f3c5e848c62821beef24d00ead81078d7c03f49232, arg=c0ce160951a2c73f733c573db352d13ccb953c9d2313f09b2535118c02a906b473877c981b7afd44cb15461a567bb788e10522d8bfbb13288f11ee7e1cf0f23c
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2330: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1976: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1811: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1727: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1552: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:2160: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:980: main::do_install_packages
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:732: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ\yKP08lsWBY/luatex.win32.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\rCImd3CKoo
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luatex.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install luatex.win32
Will be retried later.
Installing [37/64, time/total: 00:29/01:00]: makeindex [460k]
Installing [38/64, time/total: 00:30/01:01]: makeindex.win32 [18k]
Installing [39/64, time/total: 00:30/01:01]: metafont [80k]
Installing [40/64, time/total: 00:30/01:00]: metafont.win32 [142k]
Installing [41/64, time/total: 00:31/01:02]: mflogo [242k]
Installing [42/64, time/total: 00:31/01:02]: mfware [102k]
Installing [43/64, time/total: 00:32/01:03]: mfware.win32 [58k]
Installing [44/64, time/total: 00:32/01:03]: modes [294k]
Installing [45/64, time/total: 00:32/01:02]: pdftex [1610k]
Installing [46/64, time/total: 00:34/01:03]: pdftex.win32 [693k]
Installing [47/64, time/total: 00:34/01:01]: plain [70k]
Installing [48/64, time/total: 00:35/01:03]: tex [77k]
Installing [49/64, time/total: 00:35/01:03]: tex-ini-files [5k]
Installing [50/64, time/total: 00:35/01:03]: tex.win32 [130k]
Installing [51/64, time/total: 00:36/01:04]: texlive-common [471k]
Installing [52/64, time/total: 00:36/01:03]: texlive-docindex [159k]
Installing [53/64, time/total: 00:37/01:05]: texlive-en [1848k]
Installing [54/64, time/total: 00:38/01:02]: texlive-msg-translations [138k]
Installing [55/64, time/total: 00:38/01:02]: texlive-scripts [344k]
Installing [56/64, time/total: 00:39/01:03]: texlive-scripts.win32 [36k]
Installing [57/64, time/total: 00:39/01:03]: tlgs.win32 [6674k]
Installing [58/64, time/total: 00:45/01:00]: tlpsv.win32 [1411k]
Installing [59/64, time/total: 00:46/01:00]: tlshell [27k]
Installing [60/64, time/total: 00:46/01:00]: tlshell.win32 [2599k]
Installing [61/64, time/total: 00:48/00:58]: unicode-data [289k]
Installing [62/64, time/total: 00:49/00:59]: updmap-map [295k]
Installing [63/64, time/total: 00:50/01:00]: wintools.win32 [5816k]
Installing [64/64, time/total: 00:56/00:59]: xdvi [175k]
Retrying to install: luahbtex.win32 [1515k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ\mKPyES02sC/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=5e395b24bd9e710be88f1f2e2a3bd18022daf3cf1e2be18d27192eccea50f5ddaa122c6ae8cd4cce6b54d3a8608ae9e119d0dbf25d1e37aa2da8a986aa0a0c70, arg=04f90e04de858fb120852cebd84671f026b355fd1ac1acb5fee48f559f06709f8c25fa4f2ccf84a602de92ff728de5bfdc97610325c803540b349c2c3f1faf18
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2330: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1976: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1811: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1727: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1566: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:2160: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:980: main::do_install_packages
 -> C:/Users/mishk/Downloads/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:732: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\CquMnkiesJ\mKPyES02sC/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\mishk\AppData\Local\Temp\nBsmWFlBXt
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --repository http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
or
  install-tl-advanced.bat --repository http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
```

Comment: you will have to wait, you are not alone. It has been already reported on the texlive list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for the information. Shoul I close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and the same error messages reinstalling TexLive, both on clean Windows and during an upgrade.

As a workaround, you may download the TexLive2020 ISO and use it instead of the network installer which is searching the latest package repo. Present ISO has date 2020-04-06.
You may find the download at CTAN Directory systems/texlive/Images or follow the link:
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images

After mounting the image, run the "install-tl-windows.bat" as admin and follow normal install (verify that the install is pointing to the ISO and not net.repo).

Comment: And of course: after installation is complete, you may use the TeX Live Manager to update the packages to latest network repo. 

I have tested with updating all packages but i avoided ".Win32" packages as the "luahbtex.win32"/"luajittex.win32 " and similar

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, it works

Comment: Great!
Just to notice - When inside the Tex Live Manager(after installation) I see the suspected packages: "luahbtex.win32"/"luajittex.win32 " are in rev. 54250 locally, while in remote repo they are in 55114. So I will avoid updating these packages until a new rev. is available in remote repo. All other packages were updated successfully, and I tested my installation trough some documents